# Windows Phone 7 Browser Helper Objects?

Tags: windows-phone-7, bho

Are Windows Phone 7 BHOs possible? I have a BHO for Windows Mobile that I'd like to port to Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know that [Windows Mobile supported BHO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158758.aspx) but I am pretty sure that Windows Phone does not support BHOs as they require the IWebBrowser2 interface and COM interop, neither of which are supported on Windows Phone. All apps in Windows Phone are built in managed code using the Silverlight runtime. You do have access to a [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431797%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), which allows you to display simple HTML/CSS/Javascript content, but does not allow you to include plugins or extensions.